# Count rows after value 1 where rest of rows are NAs in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this data:

```
df <- tibble(a = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA))
```

I want to fill the NAs after the occurence of 1 with counts. Like this:

```
df2 <- tibble(a = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3))
```

I've no solution so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible way to solve this within the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    # return TRUE or FALSE (1 or 0) if is not NA and run cummulative sum to identify groups
    dplyr::mutate(grp = cumsum(!is.na(a))) %>% 
    # build grouping
    dplyr::group_by(grp) %>% 
    # give rownumber per group if group != 0 (first rows until a = 1 for the frist time
    dplyr::transmute(a = ifelse(grp != 0, dplyr::row_number(), NA)) %>%  
    # release groupings to prevent unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    # unselect grp if you do not need it further on in your calculations
    dplyr::select(-grp)

# A tibble: 9 x 1
      a
  <int>
1    NA
2    NA
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     1
8     2
9     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, a2 := seq_len(.N) * NA^(all(is.na(a))), cumsum(!is.na(a))]
```

-output

```
> df
    a a2
1: NA NA
2: NA NA
3:  1  1
4: NA  2
5: NA  3
6: NA  4
7:  1  1
8: NA  2
9: NA  3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sequence`:

```r
idx = which(df$a == 1)
df$a[idx[1]:length(df$a)] <- sequence(diff(c(idx, length(df$a) + 1)))

#df$a
#[1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  1  2  3
```